# brew link error

Tags: macos, homebrew

many times I do brew install and I keep getting error unable to link, and brew doesnt give what it is not able to link to, it does tell what it is able to, time back I manually did it but now I forgot, however I want to fix this issue of linking error from brew once and for all,

does anyone have any clue whats the cause  and how to fix it forever ?

```
macHost:Volumes userName$ brew install gqview
Error: You must `brew link libtiff libpng` before gqview can be installed

macHost:Volumes userName$ brew link libtiff libpng
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/4.0.6... 
Error: Could not symlink share/man/man3/TIFFClose.3tiff
/usr/local/share/man/man3 is not writable.
```

Comment: `/usr/local/share/man/man3` seems to missing or unwriteable, can you verify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `/usr/local` writable by userName for brew installation to work.
Trying running this:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked after this step: I gave write permission to `/usr/local/share/man/man3` using below cmd

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/share/man/man3
```